# I get an error when I type git commit -m "My message"

Tags: git, compiler-errors, commit

This is the error I receive. Check the below image
[image]

Comment: You should add more information, to avoid your question will be vote down or close.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do: set your email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the suggested commands. For example:

```
git config --global user.name "Aishwarya Mohan"
git config --global user.email mohan@domain.com.invalid
```

Of course, substitute your actual email address on the latter command.